# Read in image Sequence of raw with OpenCV and LV

Tags: c++, opencv, labview

I need your help as fast as possible. I transfer a string from LabView which indicated the path to the imageSequence and then read all the raw data with the following routine:

```
Mat loadImage(char* path, int SizeX, int SizeY, int type){

    Mat imOut(SizeX, SizeY, type, Scalar(0));

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char *imagedata = NULL;
    int framesize = SizeX * SizeY;
    char buffer[1000];

    // Open raw image.
    fp = fopen(path, "rb");

    // Memory allocation for image data buffer.
    imagedata = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * framesize);

    // Read image data and store in buffer.
    fread(imagedata, sizeof(char), framesize, fp);

    memcpy(imOut.data, imagedata, framesize);

    free(imagedata);

    fclose(fp);

    return imOut;

}


__declspec(dllexport) INT medianImgSeq(ushort SizeX, ushort SizeY, int stringL,  char *src, ushort *dst, ushort *debugValue){

WIN32_FIND_DATAA found;
HANDLE hFind;

// Alloc Memory
char path[1000];
char *result; 
char directory[1000];
char directoryConCat[1000];
char temp[1000];


vector<Mat> imgSeq;
vector<ushort> med;


int fileCnt(0);
int indexChar(0);
int medianValue(0);

// Copy path from string
std::strcpy(path, src);

// Get directory from path
result = std::strrchr(path, '\\');
indexChar = (int)(result-path+2);

for(int i = 0;i < indexChar;i++){

    directory[i] = path[i];
    directoryConCat[i] = path[i];

    // Convert to String
    if(i == indexChar-1){ 

        directory[i] = '*';
        directory[i+1] = '\0';
        directoryConCat[i] = '\0';
    }
}   
strcpy(temp, directoryConCat);
// Load in image sequence
hFind = FindFirstFileA(directory, &found);

if(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    do{
            if((found.cFileName[0] == '.') || (found.cFileName[1] == '.')) continue;
            fileCnt++;

            imgSeq.push_back(loadImage(std::strcat(directoryConCat, found.cFileName), SizeX, SizeY, CV_16U).clone());
            *directoryConCat = NULL;
            strcpy(directoryConCat, temp);

    }while(FindNextFileA(hFind, &found));
}

return 0;
}
```

The problem is now that only half of the image is read in (1536*1920).
Do you have an idea where the bug could be?

Comment: try: `int framesize = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * SizeX* SizeY;`

Answer (score 0):

Your image is defined as **CV_16U**,
but you are reading from the file as if it was 8bit (**char**).

You should update your **loadImage** function to consider "type" parameter.